# Abandoned Cart Behavioral Trigger - Missing Contacts in Data Extensions

Tags: javascript, einstein, track, behavioral-triggers

I have Einstein Collect Code running and it appears to be capturing all users and associated data. For example, I can look up a specific email address (in Einstein-> Reporting-> Contacts) and see products they viewed, along with an active, abandoned cart.

When I go to the 'abandonedcart' data extension, this contact is not present at all.

When I look in the 'Status' section, I see 5k 'Track Cart Activity' events for today. However, there are only 150 contacts in the 'abandonedcart' data extension.

Simply put, it appears the Einstein collect code is working perfectly, but not all abandoned carts are making it to the data extension.

Thank you in advance for any assistance here.